# Is there a metric in kubernetes cAdvisor that can tell how many endpoints are there for a NodePort/ClusterIP?

Tags: kubernetes, cadvisor

I'm looking to monitor the number of active Endpoints in NodePort and ClusterIP service. There are several cases when my pods restart or get destroyed. So its important to know if atleast one Endpoint is there to serve the incoming request.
Is there some metric for it in cAdvisor that I can expose via Prometheus? If not is there some way to track this?

Comment: you can monitor a number of pods? why endpoint? its the service the will maintain the endpoint, not the pods. the endpoint will exist if the service exist and the service will update the endpoint when pods up

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about cadvicer for monitoring endpoints but by using prometheus blackbox we can achieve this.

The Prometheus Blackbox exporter allows endpoints exploration over several protocols, such as HTTP(S), DNS, TCP, and ICMP. This exporter generates multiple metrics on your configured targets, like general endpoint status, response time, redirect information,Detecting endpoint failures, or certificate expiration dates.

Refer to this [link](https://www.infracloud.io/blogs/monitoring-endpoints-kubernetes-blackbox-exporter/) for installation and to configure the setup.